# Application Error for Angular app on Azure App Service

Tags: angular, azure

I'm fairly late to the Azure (and wow there is loads of stuff out there...) and I'm having an issue with Angular 6 solution on App Service. I've successfully deployed from the Azure extension in VS Code.

When going to my site, I receive this error:

> :( Application Error
>   If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

So I check out the log files:

```
Container XXX didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start
Container XXX for site mySite did not start within expected time limit.

INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_7b4d117f. Elapsed time = 189.101504 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_7b4d117f. Elapsed time = 204.1912079 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_7b4d117f. Elapsed time = 219.2921354 sec
ERROR - Container XXXX0_7b4d117f for site XXX did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.3799399 sec
ERROR - Container XXXX0_7b4d117f didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
INFO  - Stoping site XXX because it failed during startup.
INFO  - Starting container for site
INFO  - docker run -d -p 1792:8080 --name XXXX0_47f85fe3 -e WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=12-lts -e APPSETTING_WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=12-lts -e PORT=8080 -e WEBSITES_PORT=8080 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=XXX -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=XXX.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=85637570d2afe11aba231532d54fa3058f66c9b70fd112bdfcd7e685b14724dd appsvc/node:12-lts  

INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container XXXX0_47f85fe3 for site XXX
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 15.2084533 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 30.3264573 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 48.8457842 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 63.959506 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 79.0436441 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 94.1302981 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 109.2186966 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 124.2962824 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 139.3960781 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 154.4925326 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 169.6122361 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 184.7178358 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 199.8274903 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 214.891633 sec
INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container XXXX0_47f85fe3. Elapsed time = 229.9826815 sec
ERROR - Container XXXX0_47f85fe3 for site XXX did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 231.0152526 sec
ERROR - Container XXXX0_47f85fe3 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
INFO  - Stoping site XXX because it failed during startup.
INFO  - Starting container for site
INFO  - docker run -d -p 6823:8080 --name XXXX0_d3d32605 -e WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=12-lts -e APPSETTING_WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=12-lts -e PORT=8080 -e WEBSITES_PORT=8080 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=XXX -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=XXX.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=85637570d2afe11aba231532d54fa3058f66c9b70fd112bdfcd7e685b14724dd appsvc/node:12-lts
```

What I've done:

> added WEBSITES_PORT and PORT with value 8080 in the Application Settings under Configuration

I've tried a handful of ports just out of curiosity but it appears nothing changes as I'm still getting the error message. Note that once the settings are saved, I restart and try again.

My questions:

- What steps can I take to resolve this issue? Is there another setting I need to change elsewhere? Do I need to set something in angular.json?
- Are there any more features I can enable that would be beneficial?
- Can anyone point me additional documentation on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a VM and hosting the Angular App on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

One suggesiton would be to access the files by navigating to your **`Appservice -> Advanced Tools ->`** And then select Debug **`console ->CMD`** it will show up all the files deployed under site/wwwroot path.

Comment: it looks like all the files are there. I did find that the WEBSITES_PORT is 4200 under the AppSettings under the Environment in Advanced Tools.